# Xcode commands via OS X Terminal

Tags: xcode

I have `Mac OS X` version `10.5.7` so I downloaded `Xcode` version `4.6.3` and launched it.

According to many tutorials (such as [this](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/)) I am supposed to install further command line tools via terminal: `xcode-select --install`

But all I get is a little manual page:

```
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
```

I went into the `Applications` directory and tried to run the command from there, but the same outcome.

In fact, the content of my `Applications` directory revealed through the following command is strange:

```
~ cd Applications

~ ls
Chrome Apps.localized
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What's your `xcode-select` version? (type `xcode-select -v` into your terminal). Mine is 2343 and it understands `--install` very well

Comment: Try the the Ask Different (Mac power users) stack exchange, if no one here knows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Mine is version ` 2308 `. Do you just launch the `Terminal ` and enter the command or do you `cd ` to a particular directory?